# c++ design query

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I am designing a framework in c++ which is supposed to provide basic functionality and act as interface for the other derived systems.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Module
{
  public:
    virtual void print()
    {
        printf("Inside print of Module\n");
    }
};
class ModuleAlpha : public Module
{
  public:
    void print()
    {
        printf("Inside print of ModuleAlpha\n");
    }
    void module_alpha_function()  /* local function of this class */
    {
        printf("Inside module_alpha_function\n");
    }
};
class System
{
  public:
    virtual void create_module(){}
   protected:
    class Module * module_obj;
};
class  SystemAlpha: public System
{
  public:
    void create_module()
    {
        module_obj = new ModuleAlpha();
        module_obj->print(); // virtual function, so its fine.

        /* to call module_alpha_function, dynamic_cast is required,
         * Is this a good practice or there is some better way to design such a system */
        ModuleAlpha * module_alpha_obj = dynamic_cast<ModuleAlpha*>(module_obj);
        module_alpha_obj->module_alpha_function();
    }
};

main()
{
   System * system_obj = new SystemAlpha();
   system_obj->create_module();
}
```

Edited the code to be more logical and it compiles straight away. The question is, that is there a better way to design such a system, or dynamic_cast is the only solution. Also, if there are more derived modules,  then for type-casting, there is some intelligence required in the base Module class.

Comment: What's the use case scenario for this kind of thing? As you've probably (correctly) realized, there might be a fundamental design problem if your base classes need knowledge of the derived class.

Comment: The use case is something like this- Base represents a system and Base2 represents modules in the system. I want to generalise the way in which the system and the modules are created, how these modules interact with each other in the system and across systems. So, to make a generic way in which modules interact, they have to be part of Base class.

Answer (score 0):

If `Derived` is the only concrete instance of `Base` you could use `static_cast` instead.

Personally, I define a function, like `MyCast` for every specialized class. I define four overloaded variants, so that I can down-cast const and non-const pointers and references. For example:

```
  inline Derived       * MyCast(Base       * x) { return static_cast<Derived *>      (x); }
  inline Derived const * MyCast(Base const * x) { return static_cast<Derived const *>(x); }
  inline Derived       & MyCast(Base       & x) { return static_cast<Derived &>      (x); }
  inline Derived const & MyCast(Base const & x) { return static_cast<Derived const &>(x); }
```

And likewise for Derived2 and Base2.

The big advantage in having all four is that you will not change constness by accident, and you can use the same construct regardless if you have a pointer or a reference.

Of course, you could replace `static_cast` with a macro, and use `dynamic_cast` in debug mode and `static_cast` is release mode.

Also, the code above can easily be wrapped into a macro, making it easy to batch-define the functions.

Using this pattern, you could then implement your code as:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
   virtual void func2() 
   { 
     base2_obj = new Derived2();
   }
   void DerivedFunc()
   {
     MyCast(base2_obj)->Derived2Func();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its good if we have only a single derived class, but when we have multiple derived classes from the same base class, casting to a specific derived class needs some intelligence stored in the base class. Is there any better way to design such a system and also avoid that intelligence in the base class or casting base pointer?

Answer (score 0):

The design gets much cleaner if `Base` does not contain the `base_obj` object, but rather gets a reference via a virtual method. `Derived` should contain a `Derived2` object, like:

```
class Base
{
  public:
      virtual void func1();
  private:
      class Base2;
      virtual Base2& get_base2();
};
class Derived : public Base
{
         Derived2 derived2;
   public:
         Base2& get_base2() { return derived2; }
         void DerivedFunc()
         {
              derived2->Derived2Func();
         }
}
```

If you are worried about performance, pass the reference in the constructor of `Base`.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code with its many compile errors and tried to simplify it. Is this what you are trying to acheive? It will compile.

```
class Base2 {
  public:
     virtual void Derived2Func(){
     }
};

Base2* fnToInstantiateABase2();

class Base {
  public:
     Base()  : base2_obj(fnToInstantiateABase2()) {
     }
     virtual void DerivedFunc() {
     }
  protected:
     Base2* base2_obj;
};
class Derived : public Base {
  public:
     void DerivedFunc() {
        base2_obj->Derived2Func(); // not possible as base2_obj is of type Base2
     }
};


class Derived2 : public Base2 {
  public:
     void Derived2Func() {
     }
};


void test() {
  Base * base_obj = new Derived();
  base_obj->DerivedFunc();
}

Base2* fnToInstantiateABase2() {
  return new Derived2();
}
```

Comment: The program you have posted does not answer the question. Derived2Func is not supposed to be a virtual function in the Base2 class, but rather a local function of Derived2 class. So the actual question was, how to call Derived2Func from Base2 object instantiated with Derived2 class.

Comment: I'm confused. I don't understand the question. Maybe you should repost your code and give the classes meaningfull names. Make sure it compiles.

Comment: I can't comment on your question. Don't have the rep! Couldn't you just make module_alpha_function virtual in its base class? Why the agonizing?

Comment: Yes I can make it virtual, if the function is supposed to be prototype for all the derived classes. But that's not always the case, Derived classes may have its own functionality very unique to themselves. So to access those functions using base pointer, we need something like this.

Comment: It would be more understandable to me if you called the classes by their names instead of base and derived. I am still baffled as to why we have a problem.